# How to join group objects into one

Tags: groups

I have imported and duplicated a mesh from a group instance. But now I have many of them on my list under scenes tab. How can I put them all in one place( like a folder , to select them all at once). [image]

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to organize them conveniently, you can simply group them into a new group (or several, if needed). To select all objects within a group, first, switch the Outliner's *Type* display mode to **Groups**, then click on the icon(s):

[image]

If you want to remove them out of those empties, you can press <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> to make all selected duplicates real, instead of instancing:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way to do that in Blender, but you can create an empty and then parent them all to it. That will place them all inside the empty's listing in the Outliner, out of the way. After creating the empty, just click and drag the objects into it in the Outliner. You should also give the empty a good name to distinguish what it's there for, so you don't have to remember when you come back months later and wonder where all your objects are.

Comment: Just checked my answer to make sure it actually works. I realized that you need to parent the objects with the Keep Transforms option.